# Is it a good idea to buy and hold Bitcoin via CFDs?

Tags: cryptocurrency, cfd

Is it a good idea to buy and hold (from few months to 2 years) Bitcoin, or even stocks for that matter, via CFD (Contract For Difference)? The advantages (through some brokers) that I have found for the Bitcoin case are:

- No deposit fees;
- No withdrawal fees;
- No trading fees besides spreads;
- No daily rollover costs by selecting 1:1 leverage;
- Not having to deal with hot/cold wallets and private keys;
- No fear of your exchange getting hacked or of losing your coins in any way;
- No management fees like publicly traded BTC trusts have;

The best metaphor to describe why I believe CFDs are interesting is that they behave like the new mobility platforms. You don't want/need to own the car/scooter (with all the associated headaches), you just want to go from A to B. I was not able to find any cryptocurrency exchange coming even close to this kind of conditions. The main downside of the CFD approach is if the broker goes bust. According to Investopedia, such an event seems unlikely and presents little risk.

> Although history does not contain too many examples of brokerage firms
> imploding, it does happen. This article explains the basic protections
> for investors and what to expect if a broker goes out of business.
>
> Sometimes brokerage firms fail due to impropriety or through no fault
> of their own, but often client assets are safe.

https://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/050515/what-happens-when-stock-broker-goes-bust.asp

However, by storing the actual BTC yourself, you would not have any problem. Am I risking the CFDs to become worthless in that case? Do you see other issues with this approach?

Comment: Let's be clear: you do not hold BTC when you hold a CFD. You hold a CFD that gives you the price difference ,but this is absolutely NOT the same as holding the underlying asset. And there is no management fee to hold BTC - just do not use a trust. ALL - every single - advantage you talk off is hogwash (and yes, I mean hogwash - made up) except one (choose cold wallet or exchange hack).Just open an account, buy BTC through a broker and put it in insured custody.

Comment: @TomTom thank you for your comment. However, that's what I wrote myself in the last line "by storing the actual BTC yourself"... Of course you won't hold BTC, but since I don't care about the actual BTC, why should I try to hold it? It is the same argument of the new mobility platforms, you don't want/need to own the car, you just want to get from A to B. Why bothering to open custody, paying for insurance etc. when you can just buy a CFD? Besides this, how can you say that sound money (i.e commissions calculated as percentage points of your trades or withdrawals) is hogwash?

Comment: I’m voting to close this because questions seeking specific investment information or buy/sell advice are off-topic.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea I don't know where you read anything of that sort. Maybe you are referring to another question? My request is about the fitness of CFDs as an alternative to holding the real asset for longer timeframes instead of the usual daily speculations that CFDs are used for. I haven't asked if Apple is good buy at the moment or whether I should short Netflix.

Comment: Your question is titled *"**Is it a good idea to buy** and hold [... some specific security...]"*. To ask about the pros & cons of CFDs vs. other ways of speculating in some asset, the question should be phrased differently -- and certainly titled differently. There are some on-topic components to your question, but your title makes it a request for buy/sell advice. Those kinds of questions attract the wrong kinds of answers (and already there is one deleted answer which started as *"Bitcoin will die within 3 years [...]"*, and which said zero about the pros/cons of CFDs etc.)

Answer (score 1):

One of the cardinal rules of investing is that if it's easy, you will lose your money.

Watch out for anything in investing that is described as "easy" or "convenient".

The people who make money with their money are the ones who put in the long hours to figure everything out right.

Comment: What a nice helpful and on-topic reply!

Comment: @98418 Spoken like someone who is about to lose all their money.

Comment: @FiveBagger I really like what you've written. Is there a book or a talk about it ? or something else.

Comment: @Yairopro Do you mean what I have written in general on this forum?

Comment: @FiveBagger I am talking about the cardinal rules of investing you have said here "if it's easy, you will lose your money". And "The people who make money with their money are the ones who put in the long hours to figure everything out right". I am just asking if there is more content about this subject (videos or books). Because it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Yairopro I suggest reading "One Up on Wall Street" by Peter Lynch. That one short book will tell you 95% of what you need to know about equity investing. The only thing it does not cover are non-standard investments. For general life rules about investing I recommend reading "The Life of P. T. Barnum: Written By Himself." (1855)

Comment: @FiveBagger Thanks